# How to implement Spring AnonymousAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, security, filter, spring-security

I want to implement an AnonymousAuthenticationFilter but don't know how to proceed.  We have a sign on page with a "forgot password" link.  However, we do not want to show this link unless the user is a valid user.  Therefore, we will attempt to use Spring AnonymousAuthenticationFilter to detect if a certain cookie is found.  If the cookie is found, we'll use Spring security taglib to display the link and the codes to handle that link.

Yes, the cookie can be expired or the user switched machine or browser.  We want the users to call us if indeed they want to change password and the "forgot password" link is not there.

The tricky part is that I don't know how to implement such AnonymousAuthenticationFilter since we already have configured an authentication manager in our security-context.xml.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make any sense. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` is implemented internally and it's purpose is described in [the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#anonymous). It's not something you would generally create another version of yourself and doesn't have anything to do with checking cookies or other submitted authentication data.

If you want to check for a cookie, then you can just do so directly in a controller which renders the login form and also the one which implements the send password link. You can set the cookie when an authenticated user accesses a secure part of the site for the first time.

Comment: I think that your solution will work.  I am new to Spring Security; therefore, I was on an auto pilot thinking that things prior to isAuthenticated() should be anonymous authentication.  I have also been looking into ways to implement custom filter.  I think I might over complicating things too much here.  Therefore, I think that the "/" controller that forwards to the login.jsp should be responsible to decide how it should render the initial screen; hence the cookie and hiding links, and etc.  Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's better that way since you can do it without having to worry much about Spring Security integration at all. You just need to be able to check that a user is authenticated when you set the cookie. That information should also be available from the `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser` method for example.